# Align div's next to each other

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

As you might see, im having some problems aligning 4 divs next to each other:[image]

For some reason i cant get them to be aligned. 
Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

html:

```
<?php foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div class="frontPost">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">

                    <div class="crop">
                        <img class="postImg" src="<?php the_field('frontimg')?>" alt="frontImg">
                    </div>
                    <p class="postTitle"> <?php the_title()?> </p>
                    <p class="postIntro"> <?php the_field('introduction') ?> </p>
            </a>
        </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

css:

```
.crop {
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.frontPost{
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.bigTxt{
letter-spacing: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
}

.postTitle{
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.postIntro{
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: can you give me link to see it a live?

Comment: Have you tried to set display:block on .frontPost instead of inline-block?

Comment: Rohil: For now its only locally.

Comment: Robjez: Yes. i have tried that

Comment: give frontPost vertical-align:top

Comment: Wow... thanks Pete! I must be really tired today :)

Comment: Can you use float:left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using vertical-align property. Use the code below for css

```
.crop {
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.frontPost{
vertical-align:top;
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.bigTxt{
letter-spacing: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
}

.postTitle{
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.postIntro{
text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Where your CSS code is showing inline-block add this rule to it.

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Output:

```
.frontPost{
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This will then make all of the divs align at the top of the parent div.

A useful link to read through! - http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/